# border-box Model somehow not working

Tags: html, css

Really simple here. Why is the border outside the box-model although i choose border-box?

```
<div class="tabswitch"> 
 <a href="#" class="active">Text 1</a>
 <a href="#" class="">Text 2</a>
</div>

.tabswitch a {
    border: 5px solid #333;
    padding: 10px 46px;       
    display: inline-block;  
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.tabswitch a.active {
    background-color: #00f;
    color: #fff;
    border: none;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DgFZZ/2/

Answer (score 2):

Apparently `box-sizing` only works on block level elements.

Remove the `inline block` (use float instead) and the width includes the border.

Demo:
http://jsbin.com/aFoyITA/1/edit